# Better way to update Properties of List of Objects

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a functionality where I have a list of objects. I need to get a final list of objects that has one of object properties modified. Currently it takes about 58 minutes but I need to have this process finish within 6 minutes. I am looking for some feedback from members and see how I can improve this code for under 6 min. Appreciate any input.

```
// Start with a List of ListItems with 350K records 
// ListItem(id, Name, Category, State, SortId)

List<ListItem> resultlist = new List<ListItem>();
List<ListItem> filterList = new List<ListItem>();

// List has 350K recrods
foreach (ListItem item in processList)
{
    // filter the lsit for particular id. 
    var filterList = processList.Where(p => p.Id == item.Id);

    // Additional logic to update the Category of the ListItem
    String AssignedCategory = GetFinalCategory() 

  // update all the filterList with AssignedCategory
    foreach (var item2Add in filterList)
    {
        item2Add.Category = AssignedCategory
        resultlist.Add(item2Add);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? List.Where(p => p.Id == item); should be List.Where(p => p.Id == item.Id); ?

Comment: The code that Marcus points to also seems redundant in the foreach loop. If there are 1000 items with the same ID, you will be performing the task 999 times more than necessary. Each of those would be added to the second foreach loop multiple times as well.

Comment: Does `GetFinalCategory()` ever change values? I can't see anything here that should take an hour to run on 350,000 records.

Comment: @MarcusHöglund is right I don't think that linq expression will work. You may need to refactor your logic a bit. Hope my answer helps solve your problem.

Comment: Naming your list `List` can be confusing, and does nothing to convey what is in it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have modified the code, hopefully it's more readable. GetFinalCategory is a method call that does some logic based on number of records in filterList. This part of logic isn't the problem. The issue is with the part where it needs to select (List.Where(p => p.Id == item.Id)).

Comment: I tried using ToLookup and that was even slower. List.ToLookup(p => p.Id == item.Id);

Comment: Updated my answer @JayShukla

Answer (score 1):

You could use the parallel task library to make it multi threaded and speed up the processing.

```
    Parallel.ForEach(resultList, (currentResult) =>{
       // Property changing logic here.
    });
```

[You can find more information here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)

Comment: I will give this a try...

Answer (score 1):

In your first foreach you are looping over each item in the processList.
Then foreach item you get you are filtering out all items that matches the current
item id against the processList. This will be done foreach item in the processList which means
that if you have more than one item with the same Id you will have redundent work.

What you should do instead is looping over every unique Id in the processList in your main foreach 
which will reduce the iterations and remove the redundant work.

```
var resultlist = new List<ListItem>();
var filterList = new List<ListItem>();

foreach (var id in processList.Select(i=> i.Id).Distinct())
{
    // filter the list for particular id. 
    var filterList = processList.Where(p => p.Id == id);

    // additional logic to update the Category of the ListItem
    var assignedCategory = GetFinalCategory() 

    // update all the filterList with assignedCategory
    foreach (var item2Add in filterList)
    {
        item2Add.Category = assignedCategory
        resultlist.Add(item2Add);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think @Sudsy1002 makes a good point in the comments as well. I'd consider adding something about it.